# How to run flyway:clean before migrations in a SpringBoot app?

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am using Springboot and Flyway. The migrations work just fine but I wanted to be able perform a `clean` flyway command when the application context gets loaded with `test` profile.

Is it possible to configure SpringBoot to do `clean` and then `migrate` if active profile is `test`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can overwrite the Flyway autoconfiguration like this:

```java
@Bean
@Profile("test")
public Flyway flyway(DataSource theDataSource) {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(theDataSource);
    flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration");
    flyway.clean();
    flyway.migrate();

    return flyway;
}
```

In Spring Boot 1.3 (current version is 1.3.0.M1, GA release is planned for September), you can use a FlywayMigrationStrategy bean to define the actions you want to run:

```java
@Bean
@Profile("test")
public FlywayMigrationStrategy cleanMigrateStrategy() {
    FlywayMigrationStrategy strategy = new FlywayMigrationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
            flyway.clean();
            flyway.migrate();
        }
    };

    return strategy;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but is there a way to avoid this behavior if the server reboots only to hot-swapping? During development it's not necessary, in fact it's rather annoying, to drop the entire data base. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

in more recent versions of spring boot (eg 2.0.2) you can use the property `spring.flyway.clean-on-validation-error` if you want to use clean because of a change in the sql files

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @dunni (Thanks, by the way!), but updated to modern Java 8+

```java
@Profile("test")
@Bean
public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayCleanMigrationStrategy() {
  return flyway -> {
    flyway.clean();
    flyway.migrate();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

... and here's the Kotlin version, if needed :)

```kotlin
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
class FlywayMigrationConfig {
    @Bean
    fun flywayCleanMigrationStrategy() = FlywayMigrationStrategy {
        it.clean()
        it.migrate()
    }
}
```