# How to reload Initial Data in running Spring Boot applicaiton?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` dependency in my web-application. Spring Boot can automatically create the schema and initialize it from the root classpath locations `schema.sql` and `data.sql` on application startup, but I'm curious is there any way to re-initialize the database using very same sql-scripts after the application has already started?

I need this feature for demo mode, so that users can reset the database to initial state after they played around enough with the tables. This is how I would like my reset-controller to look like:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reset")
@Profile("demo")
public class ResetController {

    @GetMapping
    public String resetTables(HttpSession session) {
        // some code re-initializing the database 
        // form schema.sql and data.sql goes here
        session.invalidate();
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

I know, I can always use `JdbcTemplate` and its methods to drop, create and re-populate each table manually, following the logic of sql statements defined in `schema.sql` and `data.sql`, but that would be a little tedious. Maybe, Spring has some out-of-the-box method for executing those scripts against the database  which would help to reload the tables with initial demonstration data?

**Updated:**

This is one of the possible solutions based on the [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) migration, as suggested by *Charles B* in the accepted answer:

1. Add `flyway-core` dependency to the project.
2. Rename `schema.sql` and `data.sql` into `V1__schema.sql` and `V2__data.sql` following Flyway naming requirements and put them under `/resources/db/migration` directory.
3. Set `spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate` property to `true`.
4. Then, the reset-controller described above could be rewritten, as simple as this:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reset")
@Profile("demo")
public class ResetController {

    private final Flyway flyway;

    public ResetController(Flyway flyway) {
        this.flyway = flyway;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String resetTables(HttpSession session) {
        flyway.clean();
        flyway.migrate();
        session.invalidate();
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
    
}
```

Additionally, for different migration scenarios, it's possible to set `spring.flyway.locations` property referencing different SQL files - separately for each profile, or even disable Flyway migration for certain profiles by setting `spring.flyway.enabled` property to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you migrate to something like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/), you could build a controller that calls flyway's clean method like referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830441/how-to-run-flywayclean-before-migrations-in-a-springboot-app). Would be easy to migrate and maintain long term.

Comment: Thank you. It works and doesn't take much effort to implement. I updated my original post with short instruction based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot makes it really easy to manage our database changes in an easy way.
We can use the data.sql and schema.sql files in Spring.

If we run our application, Spring Boot will create an empty table for us, but won't populate it with anything.

More details here -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Spring Boot Actuator endpoints to restart your entire application. That should reinitialize your ORM and reset the DB initial state.

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configuration:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: restart
  endpoint:
    restart:
      enabled: true
```

And you should be able to hit the `/actuator/restart` endpoint.

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/restart
```

Comment: Being honest, I would prefer to avoid having the whole application restarted. Otherwise, the user might get confused what's going on when the application becomes inaccessible (even for a moment) and what to do next. It would also take some additional actions from user (such as reload the page or similar) to get back on track. I would prefer to make this process for user as smooth as possible, like this: the user clicks the "reset" button and gets automatically redirected to the main page after the controller accomplishes re-initialization.